# SQL First row result in reverse

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

```
SELECT item_description, item_variant, branch, GROUP_CONCAT(sum ORDER BY 'date') AS chartData
        FROM (
        SELECT item_description, item_variant, branch, SUM(sales) AS sum
        FROM inventory_branches
        WHERE (item_description = 'agapanthus') AND (date BETWEEN '2018-06' AND '2018-08')
        GROUP BY item_description, item_variant, branch, MONTH(date) DESC
        ) T
        GROUP BY item_description, item_variant, branch, MONTH('date') 
        LIMIT 5
```

The code above returns all rows correctly except for the first one. The first group of data in `chartData` is in reverse

[In the first row, the 20 should be after the 58](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXV26.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `GROUP_CONCAT(sum ORDER BY 'date' DESC) AS chartData`?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Zack no matter how I add DESC or ASC in the code, the result in the first row of `chartData` is reversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there is a column named `date` in you table. To sort by it use `ORDER BY date` and not `ORDER BY 'date'`, i.e. don't enclose the column name in single quotes. `'date'` is just a string literal, sorting by it is like not sorting at all, as it is equal for all rows.

Comment: I don't know why but I get an error saying that it's an unknown column in field list when I take away the single quotes.

Comment: @lekendary: Include it in the column list of your inner query.

Comment: it works! I didn't realize that's what it needed. Thank you!